# Why does Calcite change GROUP_CONCAT to LISTAGG?

Tags: apache-calcite

I built a `RelNode` using the following SQL:

```sql
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ename ORDER BY ename DESC SEPARATOR 'a') FROM emp
```

and I used `RelToSqlConverter` to converter it to SQL. I get this SQL:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(`ename`, 'a') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY `ename` IS NULL DESC, `ename` DESC) FROM `emp`
```

But I want to get `GROUP_CONCAT` not `LISTAGG`.

Answer (score 1):

Check https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-4349

> GROUP_CONCAT is analogous to LISTAGG (see CALCITE-2754) (and also to BigQuery and > PostgreSQL's STRING_AGG, see CALCITE-4335). For example, the query
>
> ```sql
> SELECT deptno, GROUP_CONCAT(ename ORDER BY empno SEPARATOR ';')
> FROM Emp
> GROUP BY deptno
> ```
>
> is equivalent to (and in Calcite's algebra would be desugared to)
>
> ```sql
> SELECT deptno, LISTAGG(ename, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY empno)
> FROM Emp
> GROUP BY deptno
> ```